# three.js 71 load a json model with texture and skeleton animation

Tags: json, model, three.js, load

I can't find the code snippet in three.js documentation to load a json model from Blender with texture and skeleton animation (and play it).
And it's wrong if i take old examples or answers because it's for old versions of three.js. 
Here is a basic model : 
http://www.lesmaudits.org/three/
proj.blend with text.jpg

So can you show me the code please ?